# print unicode character with PDCURSES

Tags: visual-studio, unicode, pdcurses

I compiled pdcurses (in Visual Studio Dev Console) with

```
nmake -f Makefile.vc WIDE=Y
```

so Unicode should be supported. If I try to call

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
initscr();          
// ...
printw("Press F1 to exit");
addstr("\u2659"); //Print out the unicode character
refresh();
// ...
```

I get a compiler warning (warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name ... cannot be represented in the current code page...) and no unicode character is shown on the console.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does `u8"\u2659"` work? This tells the compiler to encode the string constant as UTF-8, not the current 8-bit code page.

Answer (score 0):

I can't advise you on the compiler warning, but `addstr()` remains a narrow-character function, even in a PDC_WIDE build. You can't pass it a wide-character string. (You *can* give it a UTF-8 string, but only if a) your locale is UTF-8 -- this doesn't work well in Windows -- or b) you build PDCurses in PDC_FORCE_UTF8 mode, which in fact I recommend.) For wide-character strings, you need `addwstr()`.

Comment: UTF-8 already works very well in Windows 10's conhost (due to the requirement to support WSL, otherwise Linux apps will break). And there's even a beta option for [using UTF-8 as a locale](https://superuser.com/q/1033088/241386)